# Java regular expression prompt error character

Tags: java, regex

Usually, a regular expression can only indicate whether the statement and the rule match. I want to be able to indicate the wrong character when I'm not, what should I do。

```
Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*");
Matcher matcher = compile.matcher("abc1ac");
```

I want to make an error in the character 1.

I want to check a filter,like `(name eq '1' or nickname ne '2') and code like '''' and user.name like 'jo%'`, the value using double '' translation

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the specific character that doesn't match the pattern? OR do you mean that you just want to find out if the pattern matched or not?

Comment: Does your regex always look like this `[...]*`? Or do you want a general solution that works for any regex value and for any string?

Comment: @nullpointer I need to prompt which character is not matched

Comment: @ROMANIA I need a general solution

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with the built-in features of Java.  I can think of two alternatives: (1) get the source to the Java regex matcher, and hack on it; (2) look up Nondeterministic Finite Automaton (which may still not be good enough to handle all Java regex features)  Doing the latter will mean parsing the regex yourself.  This is going to be a very complicated problem, and I recommend you narrow down your problem (i.e. handle only very specific types of patterns)

Comment: @ajb Since there is no general solution, I will narrow down the detail problem

Comment: Can't you just replace all valid characters with ""? The remainder then only contains all rejected characters

Comment: @ajb There _is_ a general solution, see my answer.

Comment: @RolandIllig I don't think that's a general solution.  It may depend on how you interpret the question.  Your solution handles a certain class of patterns, a character class with a quantifier (see ROMANIA's comment), but not much more than that.  If your pattern is `"Index: [0-9]+"` and you give it `"Indfx: 135"`, I think the OP would want to find the character `f` or the index 3, but your solution won't do that.  That's why I suggested that OP to narrow the problem down (but his attempt just added to the confusion).

Comment: @RolandIllig You are right, Java regex can handle things are limited.If you can find a better way, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

```
I write as follow,maybe better to use design pattern.

    public class FilterExpressionException extends RuntimeException {

        private String expression;
        private int index;

        public FilterExpressionException(String expression, int index) {
            super(mark(expression, index));
            this.expression = expression;
            this.index = index;
        }

        public FilterExpressionException(String message, String expression, int index) {
            super(message + "(" + mark(expression, index) + ")");
            this.expression = expression;
            this.index = index;
        }

        private static String mark(String expression, int index) {
            return expression.substring(0, index) + '^' + expression.substring(index);
        }

        public String getExpression() {
            return expression;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

    }

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Stack;

    public class FilterExpressionParserImpl {


        private String[] relations = {"eq", "ne", "gt", "ge", "lt", "le", "like", "in", "bt"};

        private String[] logices = {"and", "or"};

        private char[][] relationChars = toCharArray(relations);

        private char[][] logicChars = toCharArray(logices);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            FilterExpressionParserImpl impl = new FilterExpressionParserImpl();
            String expr = "(name eq '' or  nickname  ne  '2' )  and (code like '''' or (user.A.name eq '''go''go''go'))";
            List<String> parse = impl.parse(expr);
            System.out.println(parse);
            List<String> strings = impl.followUp(parse);
            System.out.println(strings);
        }


        private class Variable {

            Stack<String> words = new Stack<>();

            Stack<Character> characters = new Stack<>();

            Stack<Integer> brackets = new Stack<>();

            int step = 0;

            char character;

            int commaTimes = 0;

            char[][] relations;

            char[][] logices;

            public Variable(char[][] relations, char[][] logices) {
                this.relations = relations;
                this.logices = logices;
            }
        }

        private List<String> followUp(List<String> middles) {
            List<String> afters = new ArrayList<>(middles.size());
            Stack<String> operators = new Stack<>();
            String top;
            for (String middle : middles) {
                switch (middle) {
                    case "and":
                    case "or":
                        if (operators.size() > 0 && !operators.peek().equals("(")) afters.add(operators.pop());
                        operators.push(middle);
                        break;
                    case "(":
                        operators.push(middle);
                        break;
                    case ")":
                        while (!(top = operators.pop()).equals("(")) afters.add(top);
                        break;
                    default:
                        afters.add(middle);
                }
            }
            while (!operators.isEmpty()) afters.add(operators.pop());
            return afters;
        }

        private List<String> parse(String filter) {
            filter = filter.trim();

            Variable variable = new Variable(relationChars, logicChars);
            for (int i = 0; i < filter.length(); i++) {
                variable.character = filter.charAt(i);
                switch (variable.character) {
                    case ' ':

                        if (variable.characters.isEmpty()) continue;
                        switch (variable.step) {

                            case 0:
                                dealPropertyPathEnd(filter, i, variable);
                                break;

                            case 1:
                                dealRelationEnd(variable);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                dealValueEnd(filter, i, variable);
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                dealLogicEnd(variable);
                                break;
                        }

                        pushWord(variable);
                        break;
                    case '(':

                        if (variable.step != 0) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
                        variable.words.push(String.valueOf(variable.character));
                        variable.brackets.push(i);
                        break;
                    case ')':

                        if (variable.brackets.size() == 0) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
                        variable.brackets.pop();

                        if (variable.step == 2 && !variable.characters.isEmpty()) {
                            dealValueEnd(filter, i, variable);
                            pushWord(variable);
                        }

                        if (variable.step != 3) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);

                        variable.words.push(String.valueOf(variable.character));
                        break;
                    default:
                        switch (variable.step) {

                            case 0:

                                if (!(isLetter(variable.character) || variable.character == '.')
                                        || ((variable.characters.size() == 0 || variable.characters.peek() == '.') && variable.character == '.'))
                                    throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
                                break;

                            case 1:

                                variable.relations = find(variable.relations, variable.characters.size(), variable.character);
                                if (variable.relations == null) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
                                break;

                            case 2:

                                if (variable.characters.size() == 0) {
                                    if (variable.character != '\'') throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
                                }

                                else {
                                    if (variable.character == '\'') variable.commaTimes++;
                                    else if (variable.commaTimes % 2 != 0) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
                                }
                                break;

                            case 3:

                                variable.logices = find(variable.logices, variable.characters.size(), variable.character);
                                if (variable.logices == null) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
                                break;
                        }
                        variable.characters.push(variable.character);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!variable.characters.isEmpty()) {

                if (variable.characters.peek() != '\'') throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, filter.length() - 1);

                if (variable.commaTimes % 2 != 1) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, filter.length() - 1 - variable.commaTimes);

                pushWord(variable);
            }

            if (!variable.brackets.isEmpty()) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, variable.brackets.firstElement());

            return variable.words;
        }

        private void pushWord(Variable variable) {
            String string = join(variable.characters);
            if (variable.step == 3) {
                if (string.equals("\'\'")) {
                    string = "";
                } else {
                    string = string.replace("\'\'", "\'");
                    string = string.substring(1, string.length() - 1);
                }
            }

            variable.words.push(string);
            variable.characters.clear();
        }

        private String join(List<Character> characters) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            characters.forEach(builder::append);
            return builder.toString();
        }


        private void dealPropertyPathEnd(String filter, int i, Variable variable) {

            if (variable.characters.peek() == '.') throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
            variable.step = 1;
        }

        private void dealRelationEnd(Variable variable) {
            variable.relations = relationChars;
            variable.step = 2;
        }

        private void dealValueEnd(String filter, int i, Variable variable) {

            if (variable.characters.peek() != '\'') throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);

            if (variable.commaTimes % 2 != 1) throw new FilterExpressionException(filter, i);
            variable.commaTimes = 0;
            variable.step = 3;
        }

        private void dealLogicEnd(Variable variable) {
            variable.logices = logicChars;
            variable.step = 0;
        }


        private boolean isLetter(char character) {
            return ('a' <= character && character <= 'z') || ('A' <= character && character <= 'Z');
        }


        private char[][] toCharArray(String[] strings) {
            char[][] chars = new char[strings.length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
                chars[i] = strings[i].toCharArray();
            }
            return chars;
        }


        private char[][] find(char[][] sources, int column, char character) {
            if (sources == null || sources.length == 0) return sources;

            List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>(sources.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
                if (sources[i].length > column && sources[i][column] == character) indexes.add(i);
            }

            if (indexes.isEmpty()) return null;

            char[][] targets = new char[indexes.size()][];
            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.size(); i++) {
                targets[i] = sources[indexes.get(i)];
            }
            return targets;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's regular expression engine can do much more than just matching text. For more information, [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LookingAt {

    public static String validate(String input, Pattern regex) {
        Matcher m = regex.matcher(input);
        if (m.matches())
            return "OK";
        if (m.lookingAt())
            return "First error at index " + m.end();
        if (m.hitEnd())
            return "Too short";
        return "Cannot match at all";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(validate("abcac", Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*")));
        System.out.println(validate("abc1ac", Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*")));
        System.out.println(validate("abcac", Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{10,}")));
        System.out.println(validate("1abcac", Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+")));
    }
}
```

Comment: It seem not work.``Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]*");
        String input = "abc1ac";
        Matcher m = compile.matcher(input);
        if (!m.matches()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
                m.reset(input.substring(0, i + 1));
                if (!m.lookingAt()) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("OK");``

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I don't think this is the general kind of solution that the OP was looking for--it only works on certain kinds of patterns.  See my above comment.  Then again, it's hard to tell just what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @RolandIllig It works fine and I learned a lot.but as ajb said,it only works on certain kinds of patterns,how do you feel about it